# Angular JS issue with get method getting 405 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi all I am having service written with one of the method as follows,

```
var GetData = function (token) {

    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
    var response = $http.get(baseurl + "api/controller/search/1/xxxx");
    return response;
};
```

When I am doing the same call in `Postman` or `fiddler` this is giving me results where as from application I am getting the following error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405
>   (Method Not Allowed)

Am I doing some thing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to your backend! Check if there is a get method on your backend API.

Comment: Hi `LXhelili` I said that I am able to get required data when using `Postman` and `Fiddler`

Comment: This sounds like an issue with [Access Control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: I have added the extension `Allow control Allow origin`to my chrome browser and testing so it should not be a issue.

Comment: No idea for now. Check you params of you url if they match.

Answer (score 0):

I think you issue may be with how you are doing the get request. Typically the $http service would get used like this :

```
$http.get(baseurl + "api/controller/search/1/xxxx").then(function(response) {
    //do something with response
    return response;
}, function (error) {
   //do something with error
   console.log(error);
});
```

If that isn't working for you, I suspect there may be an issue with the Bearer token that you are appending to the request.

Comment: Hi `jon` the same token when I am using in `Postman` it works fine am I passing it correctly?

Comment: @Dotnet Could I possibly see the network request and response that you are getting through your browser?

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://app/appcode/api/students/filter/2/2/2. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405` Here is the error from console